# How to mock Guava Maps.newConcurrentMap()

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, guava

How to mock this?

```
public class MyClass {

}
```

Comment: And why would you mock such a class?

Comment: You can't mock static methods, at least in java.

Comment: @ArthurEirich Yes you can, see e.g. [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockStatic).

Comment: @FrankPavageau I knew someone would point me to that, but I really wanted to prevent the OP start using PowerMock.

Comment: @ArthurEirich Then just say so :). We still don't know why the OP wants to mock a `ConcurrentHashMap`, which is probably the wrong answer to another problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection):

```
public class MyClass {
  private Map<String, MyClassModel> list;  // Don't initialize.

  public MyClass(Map<String, MyClassModel> list) { // Inject to ctor.
    this.list = list;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
long expectedId = 42;

ServiceRegistartor tested = new ServiceRegistartor();

mockStatic(IdGenerator.class);

expect(IdGenerator.generateNewId()).andReturn(expectedId);

replay(IdGenerator.class);

long actualId = tested.registerService(new Object());

verify(IdGenerator.class);

assertEquals(expectedId, actualId);
```

Comment: What kind of (self-) answer is that? It's just an unattributed copy/paste of the PowerMock wiki, not even adapted to match the question. Down-voting.